# Modifying Array.push in javascript returns TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let array = [];

const oldPushMethod = array.push;

array.push = (el) => {
    console.log(el);
    oldPushMethod(el);
}

array.push(10);
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at push (<anonymous>)
```

I am trying to add more functionality in `.push` method but it is returning TypeError.

How can i resolve this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is occurring because the `oldPushMethod` function is called with a `this` value of undefined or null, rather than the array object. To fix this, you can bind the oldPushMethod function to the array object before calling it:

```js
let array = [];

const oldPushMethod = array.push.bind(array);

array.push = (el) => {
    console.log(el);
    oldPushMethod(el);
}

array.push(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were calling the `oldPushMethod` in the global context, not in the context of the current array. You can use `call` to fix it. It takes 2 args `this` (the array) and your `el` to push.

```js
let array = [];

const oldPushMethod = Array.prototype.push;
array.push = function(el) {
  console.log(el);
  oldPushMethod.call(this, el);
};
array.push(10);
```